# Populate form - Smarty

Tags: javascript, php, forms, populate

Hi I have a project where I have a search form with select (with checkbox). It's wrote in Smarty Framework.

Search bar looks like we have select inputs for example to choose "Language", in the expanded select view we have checkbox input ("English", "French", ...) and we can choose multiple language.

How can I populate form with checked value, after click search button?

The form code:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <div class="language">Language</span></div>
        <div id="selectLanguage" class="selectContent">
            {foreach from=$lang key=k item=j}
                {if $k == ''}
                    <label for="all_lang"><input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" id="all_lang" value="" /> {$j}</label>
                {else}
                    <label for="{$k}"><input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" id="{$k}" value="{$k}" /> {$j}
                    </label>
                {/if}
            {/foreach}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script JS:

```
$('#search-button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#search-box form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Instead of expecting a user to click on a button, why not using the `.submit()` function properly? Like `$('form').submit()`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [{html_checkboxes}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.html.checkboxes.tpl) function where `selected` attribute can be `string` or `array` (you need this one).

If you don't want to use custom functions, you can use `array_search` modifier, e.g.

```
{if $lang.id|array_search:$smarty.post.lang}
    {* its checked *}
{/if}
```